# PubSub error in Beam app: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to read data from pub/sub topic of GCS,

```py
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        events = p | "ReadPubSub" >> beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(topic=args.topic)
```

However, the following errors come up.

```
DEBUG:google.auth.transport.requests:Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
ERROR:root:Exception at bundle <apache_beam.runners.direct.bundle_factory._Bundle object at 0x11973d3b0>, due to an exception.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py", line 343, in call
    finish_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/executor.py", line 383, in attempt_call
    result = evaluator.finish_bundle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 488, in finish_bundle
    data = self._read_from_pubsub(self.source.timestamp_attribute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py", line 483, in _read_from_pubsub
    sub_client.api.transport.channel.close()
AttributeError: 'Channel' object has no attribute 'close'
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Beam version: 2.14.0

Comment: What versions of google-cloud-pubsub, grpcio are installed (run "pip list" to see)?

Comment: Also does "pip check" give any errors?

Comment: @UdiMeiri, the version of google-cloud-pubsub is `0.39.1` and the version of grpcio is 1.11.0

Comment: @UdiMeiri, after install the latest google-cloud-pubsub, grpcio. This issue is resolved. Thank you very much..

Comment: @UdiMeiri, I have met the version compatible issue twice. Is there any way to check it?

Comment: When you install apache-beam pip should give a warning if there are incompatible versions. The "pip check" command can check for incompatibilities of currently installed packages. In this case, I believe Beam has a bug, since it lists grpcio minimum version as 1.8, but clearly even 1.11.0 is too old.

Comment: Python 2 App Engine apps have this issue because the latest version of `grpcio` on Google servers is 1.0.0 (yikes!), and we can't vendor/self-bundle/copy a newer version because it has C code. Users *must* upgrade their apps to 3.x unless Google upgrades to a newer version, but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: I was mistaken. There's a missing exception handler in the final version of the Python 2 Pub/Sub client library, so I filed a [bug](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/742) to get them to handle the exception when closing the subscriber client. Furthermore, Python 2 App Engine also seems to allow a more modern version of that client library but only older than 1.40dev, meaning the `requirements.txt` file should also have `grpcio<1.40dev` in it. It's possible that it uses the _Python_ from v1.39 which it installs but the C code from the builtin v1.0—can't confirm the last part.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in Beam dependencies. Opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7986

From the discussion above, it seems that upgrading grpcio to 1.22.0 solves the issue.

Comment: More specifically, this fix was integrated in `grpcio` version [1.12.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases/tag/v1.12.0) with [this PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/15254) fixing [this bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12531).